# Move focus to the next Edittext which is item of a Recyclerview by hitting Enter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I have created a `RecyclerView` which contains `EditText` items. When I hit Enter, it will create a new `EditText` item below and I'm trying to figure out how to move the focus to the new one, without click.

`imeOptions` didn't work.

EditTextItem:

```
public class EdittextItem {
       private String text; //text from Edittext will be save in to this String

   public String getText() {
    return text;
   }

   public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
   }
```

}

ViewHolder and OnBindVH:

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        EditText text;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }

 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

       holder.text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            list.get(position).setText(holder.text.getText().toString());

        }
    });
        holder.text.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    list.add(new EditextItem());
                  //Create new Item and i want to move focus into it.

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To move focus use `requestFocus()` method on your view.

Ref. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#requestFocus()

Comment: I'm trying to use that but I don't know how to call the Edittext from a different Item.

Answer (score 0):

Oh i found out the way. Just put this line inside `public boolean onKey`:

```
Editor.recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position+1).itemView.requestFocus();
```